# Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

First of all I have to admit that I am quite new as far as GAE concerns and that is why my question may seem stupid. I would like to keep three different entities that are related to each other.

1. Project
2. User
3. Data

User (M) <-> (N) Project (1) <-> (N) Data

Basically each project can have plenty of Data entities related to it (e.g. 10 000, 100 000).

However, I am not sure how to keep those relations among the entities in Datastore so that I can easily fetch information like:

- list all user's projects
- list all data of particular project
- list all data the user has access to (data belonging to all user's projects)

Maybe the whole idea is wrong and I should use Google Cloud SQL instead.

I would appreciate any comments.

Thank you.

Comment: Your requirements are very simple, and GAE Datastore is a perfect choice for your use case. We cannot answer your question, however, unless you tell us what language you use (Java, Python, Go), and, if Java, if you plan to use low-level Datastore API (I personally love it), Objectify, or something else.

Comment: I am gonna use Java. I have experience with JPA, however, I would like to know what is underneath. Thus I would like to see example using low-level Datastore API. I am not sure about M:N relationship between users and projects.

Answer (score 1):

which environment (Java, Python or Go) is used?

e.g. Python

1 <-> N [ReferenceProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty)

M <-> N [ListProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty)

Take a look [her](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#References) for some examples.

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Do I get it right that if I want to access projects from a user and also users from a particular project, I have to keep that ListProperty for both entities? And then I have to modify it within adding, updating or removing on both sides.